# Can a Windows 10 user be prevented from opening executables on a whole partition?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, permissions, group-policy

Is there a way to prevent a Windows 10 user (or the whole system) from opening any executable files on a whole partition? (E.g. just on the D:\ drive including all sub-folders.)

It would alternatively be possible (maybe even a better solution) to *just* allow the execution of files on the C:\ drive.

The purpose is to prevent a user from accidentally executing files such as `virus.exe` and `trojan.jpg.exe` while *retaining* their ability to use all system software and create/delete/move all files/folders and unpack archives, etc. (Basically, there should be no mitigations except for executable files.)

Comment: If your attempting to avoid ransomware, preventing the execution on what partition and allowing it on another won’t prevent the malware from encrypting any files detected on any volume the malware has access to (which is the same permissions as the user that started it).

Comment: @Ramhound: Why not? How will a user execute ransomeware if they can not execute any files on any partition besides C:\ and they have no file-explorer access to C:\? I know that there are online injection attacks, SMB vulnerabilities and someone with malicious intent could still compromise the system, this is just about preventing a regular user from accidentally executing a bad file (or maybe willingly, without understanding the consequences).

Comment: Because most malware is downloaded and run silently because of your browser.  You also assume that JavaScript and PowerShell can’t downloaded an encoded binary (executable) and then run it.  You can prevent specific executables but the name of the file must be known.  You also only allow specific executables, but again the file name, must be known which won’t be the case for a malicious file.  Your approach is deeply flawed and not easily (likely impossible) on Windows using a group policy (which is the only way to prevent the execution of an executable).

Comment: If you are going to allow your users to be Administrators (we do not allow this), then you need to train them not to go to dodgy websites and not open emails from strangers (Malware also comes via email). Have a strong spam filter in place and maintain daily off-line backups.

Comment: @Ramhound: I've already mentioned this. There is no absolute security and I am aware of that. There is also no way to prevent the usage of web browsers as an attack surface. I have to trust that it's updated, "secure browsing" features work, 3rd-party scripts are blocked and a real-time virus scan is running. That's all that can feasibly be done. Just because I can't lockdown a system 100%, doesn't mean that there is no validity to this approach, it would fix many simple issues. I know about whitelisting software by filenames, it's problematic. Maybe there can be another solution?

Comment: @John: We basically do have all of that already. However, you can not train all users. Some people are not tech-savvy, some are just not interested at all. Some might want to use "their software" that is not trustworthy. You usually get low two-digit percentages of employees regularly opening spam mail, it's a reality. We do not have the capacity to train all users to such a level of responsibility. Such a simple restriction would immediately solve a lot of issues and management work. I'd just like to know if it could be done somehow.

Comment: How about moving all the files you want people _not to run_ to the other drive and encrypt the drive with a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, we have found a solution to this question.

To reiterate/elaborate the problem:

We have multiple systems that are semi-publically accessible and have to be restricted for reasons of security and administration (No accidental execution of .exe and script files, no user-space installations).

Our systems have one Windows-Administrator and local user accounts. The Administrator has access to C:\ to install and manage software, the users just have access to a separate D:\ partition (via Group Policy: Administrative Templates - Windows Components - File Explorer - Prevent access to drives).

To prevent execution of any files from D:, we created a new **Software Restriction Policy (SRP)** (also found in the Group Policies, but in Windows Settings - Security Settings - Software Restriction Policies).

In this case, we used a whitelist-approach (Default security level set to: "Disallowed") and added the following paths as allowed: `%SystemDirectory%`, `%SystemDrive%`, `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` (The path rules recursively respect these Windows environment varables.)

This way, only software from drive C:\ is allowed to run. Since only the system administrator is able to access C:, no user-space software can be run without admin permissions, the user gets a notice.

Any incident will be recorded and visible in the system logs, so paths can be added as necessary.

This may or may not be absolutely secure against targeted attacks, but will prevent accidental execution of software or installing various unwanted programs by the general user.